# Cómo puedo validar si la librería jquery, se esta invocando dos veces en una vista

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando en los errores de codeigniter, tengo varios proyectos y elegí uno para implementar la vista de los errores y los demás lo llaman de ese proyecto "proyecto principal" pero en algunos me genera un conflicto cuando ocurre un error de PHP, el error se presenta al encontrar que se invoca dos veces Jquery, quisera validar que cuando en la vista encuentre la librería Jquery, desactive la llamada de Jquery que hace la vista del error de PHP.

Comment: Hola, lo correcto es que generaras un archivo general un libreria donde invoques lo que vayas a utilizar y para todos los demas archivos invoques esta libreria para que no tengas el problema que comentas.

Comment: puesdes crear tambien rutas bases para que atiendan los llamandos y siempre veirificar la herencia de los demas archivos

Comment: como estás cargando jquery? versión de CI?